# Facebook API - get whole user feed of a given period of time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the whole feed of a user of a given period of time (let's say for the past 24 hours).

When I make the API call /me/feed/ it seems that I only get the recent posts of a user (it also seems kinda random to me, sometimes group messages, sometimes private messages, etc.). What do I need to do to get the posts of yesterday, the day before, or maybe even of the last year?

So to speak, I want something like in Flipboard.

How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the `since` and `until` parameters that you can pass in the request...

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for! And nothing mentioned in the documentation... thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome and it **is** there alright :P Just hidden away (as most things are)... Take a look at [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)... In particular [this section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#time) that deals with time based paging. It explains the use of  `since`, `until` and also `limit`.